# Can anyone explain why the outputs are different in C and Java?

Tags: java, c++, c

```
{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     int a = 10;
     if (a == a--)
     System.out.println("first\t");
     
     a=10;
     if(a==--a)
     System.out.println("second\t");
     
 }
}
```

For the java program, output is "first", whereas for the C/C++ program its "second". The functionality of post/pre fix operations are same in both programs to my knowledge. If anyone can shed some light on the logic, it would be great as I am new to coding.

```
int main()
{
   int a = 10;
   if(a==a--)
   
       printf("first\t");
   
   a=10;
   if(a==--a)
   
       printf("second\t");
   
}
```

Comment: In C the construct `a == a--` is **Undefined Behaviour**, don't know about Java or any other language. The point is -- you can't reason about the outcome of `a == a--`, in C, in any useful way

Comment: It's UB in c++ as well.

Comment: @cigien I think it may just be Unspecified Behavior in C++ since C++17. Might be wrong though, those changes still confuse me.

Comment: No, I think this is still UB. At least compilers still warn about it.

Comment: You should rephrase the C/C++ part of the question. Those are two languages. There will be a behaviour for C and another behaviour for C++ (and maybe changes between standard version). But typically, people will dislike the two being clumped together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In java, you get the guarantee that you'll always observing this code printing `First`, and never `Second.`

In C/C++, you get no such guarantees. Depending on compiler, architecture, OS, and phase of the moon, it will likely print either only `First` or `Second` but I'm pretty sure the C and C++ spec make it 'legal' for a compiler/architecture/OS/phase-of-moon combo to end up printing BOTH `First` and `Second` or even neither.

See [order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) rules for C++: Given some binary operator construct: `a x b` where a and b are expressions and x is some binary operator, then first `a` and `b` must be evaluated, and then the `x` operator is applied to the values so obtained. Unless the operator explicitly decrees an order (which for example the `||` and `&&` operators do; they promise to short-circuit, that is, to not evaluate `b` at all, if `a` is such b cannot affect the result) - then a C(++) compiler is free to emit code such that `b` is evaluated before `a` is, or vice versa.

C is filled to the brim with such 'shoulds' and 'mays': The C spec is designed to allow C code to compile on a wide variety of chips with a ton of leeway for a compiler to apply far-reaching optimizations. It goes so far that simple primitive data types have an unspecified bitwidth.

Contrast to java, where almost everything is locked down: There are very few aspects of java code which are intentionally left unspecified, and the compiler is 'on rails' and is very very limited in what bytecode it is allowed to emit (in java, the optimizations are left to the runtime / hotspot compiler, not to `javac`).

That's why, on java, the spec *DOES* define explicitly precisely how `a x b` ought to be resolved: the java spec does decree that regardless of operator, `a` must always be evaluated before `b` is evaluated (unless, just like in C, b isn't evaluated at all due to short-circuit rules).

Going all the way back to the Java Language Specification v7, [the spec explicitly dictates the left hand side MUST be evaluated first](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.1) - and this hasn't changed since then (and I'm pretty sure was true since java 1.0, for what it's worth. It's probably chapter 15.7.1 in most JLS versions).

Comment: I 've just run the above C script with gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0
and on the 2nd label(2nd if statement) I see no comparison instruction! I am really schocked how the compiler works. Please @rzwitserloot, if you can add/elaborate this on your pretty answer, I would be happier

Comment: @Confidenc3 That's the time traveling effect of UB, I think. `a == --a` is UB, and the compiler knows it is UB. It assumes that, since it is UB, your program logic will never actually execute `a == --a`, because correct programs never commit UB. So, it simply throws out the condition as dead code. That is, `a == --a` is UB, therefore your program should never execute it, therefore it is dead code, therefore the compiler got rid of it.

Comment: @Confidence3 'why does this C code compile to this machine code' is a separate issue entirely, I think, and likely what you're observing has relatively little to do with -- or ==, and more with that the compiler either tosses it because it is UB, or, figures that it can feasibly interpret either clause in either if statement as either 'true' or 'false' literals, then further eliminating the --a part because a is local to main and used nowhere else. Thus, a C compiler can legally emit the exact same code as int main() {printf("first\t");}.

Answer (score 3):

In C and C++, the behavior of the expressions `a == a--` and `a == --a` is *undefined*:

> **6.5 Expressions**
> ...
> 2     If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect
> on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar
> object, the behavior is undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the
> subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side
> effect occurs in any of the orderings.<sup>84)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> 84) This paragraph renders undefined statement expressions such as
>
> ```
> i = ++i + 1;
> a[i++] = i;
> ```
>
> while allowing
>
> ```
> i = i + 1;
> a[i] = i;
> ```

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

C does not force left-to-right evaluation of relational and equality expressions, and it does not require that the side effect of the `--` and `++` operators be applied immediately after evaluation.  The result of `a == a--` can vary based on the compiler, hardware, even the surrounding code.

Java, OTOH, *does* force left-to-right evaluation and applies side effects immediately after evaluation, so the result is consistent and well-defined.

Answer (score 2):

In C (as the code in the second example seems to be),

1. The evaluation order of the subexpressions is unspecified, and
2. There is no sequence point between the operands of the `==` operator.

Thus, If the increment of `a` in `if (a == a++)` or decrement of `a` in `if (a == a--)` happens before the comparison to `a` itself is not defined.

The result invokes *undefined behavior*. It could give different results already at the next execution on the same machine.

In contrary, Java seems to define this behavior.